# libgdx tablelayout add image in new row

Tags: libgdx, tablelayout

I'm using libgdx and table layout in my screens.

When I add images in Table on initialize everything is fine, but when I add image to table on some event (on collision) images are placed in one column not every image in new row.

```
Table tableCenterLeft;
Image image1, image2;


    private void init() {

       tableCenterLeft = new Table();
       image1 = new Image(Assets.instance.image.image1);
       image1 = new Image(Assets.instance.image.image1);

       createUI();

    }

    private void createUI() {

    //if I add image here in init() image1 and image2 are added one below the other (fine)
       tableCenterLeft.add(image1);
       tableCenterLeft.add(image2);
    }

    private void onCollisionWithRock() {
    // if I add in some event later in game , image1 and image2 are in same column (bad)
       tableCenterLeft.add(image1);
    }
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `tableCenterLeft.row()` before `tableCenterLeft.add(image1)` if you want your table to have a new line as described in the [documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html#row--).

With your method `createUI`, the two images should be on the same row.

Comment: I want to be in the same row but they are in new line each other. This is case when I call `onCollisionWithRock` method one by one time with delay (one time call with image1, one with image2)